# Where are the NPC Pokemon traders that I can trade with, and what do they offer?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Every Pokemon game features NPCs that you can trade with in order to obtain different Pokemon, and Pokemon X and Y are no different.

I usually try and find and trade with all the NPC traders throughout a game. However so far I've only found one in Santalune City (he wants a Bunnelby for a Farfetch'd named Quacklin' - the best name ever, IMHO).

So where are all the other NPC traders? What Pokemon do they want, and what do they offer in exchange?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far that I've found, the in-game trades are as follows:

- **Bunnelby** -> **Farfetch'd**: *Santalune City* (House, West from the fountain)

  - Jolly
- **Jigglypuff** -> **Bisharp**: *Snowbelle City*  (House, Southwest of the northern bridge)

  - Adamant
- **Luvdisc** -> **Steelix**: *Cyllage City* (Pokemon Center)

  - Impish
- **Gyarados** -> **Magikarp**: *Random hotel* (Must talk to a Hiker repeatedly over the course of a few days)

  - Adamant
- **Any Pokemon** -> **Eevee**: *Random hotel* (Must talk to a woman repeatedly over the course of a few days)

  - Docile and holds a Rare Candy

### After Elite Four

- **Any Pokemon** -> **Starter**: *Vaniville Town* (outside your house)

  - You will get the starter yours is *strongest* against.
- **Any Pokemon** -> **Ralts**: *Lumiose City*, (Cafe Soleil on Southern Boulevard)

  - Comes with Gardevoirite

Comment: To add to this answer, in 2 random hotels you can get an adamant Magikarp which a Gyarados is requested for trade. In another random hotel you can get a modest Eevee at the expense of any pokemon to trade. This Eevee actually comes from Mr. Backlots manison too. I found this info here: http://www.serebii.net/xy/ingametrade.shtml