# Can you get a shiny or female Pokémon from an in-game trade?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

For example, if I trade a Bunnelby to Cliff for his Farfetche'd in Santalune City.

Comment: Related: [Where are the NPC Pokemon traders that I can trade with, and what do they offer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135473/where-are-the-npc-pokemon-traders-that-i-can-trade-with-and-what-do-they-offer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the in-game trades are preset and will always be the same exact Pokemon traded to you. The gender, nature, characteristic etc are all preset, and thus, I deduce that those Pokemon cannot be shiny.

As for whether or not they are female, some of them will be, if they were already meant to be female. Of all the in-game available Pokemon for trade, those are females:

- Stevie (Eevee) from Elena
- Thumper (Steelix) from Farris
- Ralts from Diantha

The others will be males.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, I have a shiny female Thumper the Steelix from Farris. If this one can be shiny, I have no doubt that the other in game trades can be shiny too.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence?

Answer (score -4):

Its

1 x Number of Dex x Number of Caught x Seen

It's like 1 in 6 million to Shiny from preset npcs. Easiest one is original Gold

Comment: Do you have a source for this?