# Where are the NPC traders in ORAS, and which Pokemon do they offer?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Similar to my question about the [NPC Traders in Pokemon X/Y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/135473/28182), I'm hoping to trade with all the NPC Traders in Pokemon Omega Ruby.

So where are all the NPC traders in ORAS? What Pokemon do they want, and what do they offer in exchange?

Comment: The first trade matches original Ruby/Sapphire, so I think there are probably all the traders from the originals and maybe some more.

Comment: @Chippies - I imagined they would be similar, but it's the 'maybe some more' part I'm interested in :)

Comment: @Robotnik yeah, that will probably take some time before someone makes a full list of all the new trades :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's probably gonna take a longer while to make a full list, I'm making this answer into a community wiki, so anyone can update it as they find more traders.

- Rustboro City: **Slakoth** ->  **Makuhita** ♂

  - *Brave*, Holding *X Attack*
- Fortree City: **Spinda** -> **Skitty** ♀

  - *Naughty*, Holding *Magost Berry*
- Pacifidlog Town: **Bellossom** -> **Corsola** ♀

  - *Calm*, Holding *Heart Scale*

Answer (score -2):

http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/ingametrade.shtml

Serebii has a running list that looks complete as of now.

Comment: Please summarize the information contained in the link.  That way, if the page ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it saves people a click.